# Google API autocomplete not working in rails but works after reload

Tags: ruby, google-maps-api-3, google-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add google autocomple api, but it works only after page reload and sometimes doesn't works even after ``page reload , Below is the code:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + Rails.application.secrets.google_api_key + '&libraries=places' %>
<div class="mui-textfield" data-turbolinks="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value='' id="user_id">
    <%= text_field_tag :location, nil, id: 'txtPlaces', class: "form-text", placeholder: '', required: true %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :full_address, nil, id: 'full_address', class: "form-text", placeholder: '' %>
</div>
<script>
  var ready = function () {

    var options = {
          type:['(regions)'],
          componentRestrictions: {
            country: ['au']
          }
        };

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('txtPlaces');
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
               $("#full_address").val($("#txtPlaces").val());
            });
          });
      // This is some custom requirement
        $('.save-address').on('click', function(e){

          if($("#full_address").val() !== $("#txtPlaces").val()){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $("#txtPlaces").val('');
            $(this).submit();
          }
        });
    };
    <%#*$(document).ready(ready);%>
    <%#*$(document).on('page:load', ready);%>
    $(document).on("turbolinks:load", ready);
</script>
```

I have tried both above **ready  and page:load** function as well but no luck
Other than this, below is the code to reach above page

```
<li><%= link_to('Active', admin_staffs_path(status: 'accepted'), data: { turbolinks: false })
```

Comment: Have you tried to put  `data-turbolinks="false"` on your page’s wrapper instead that in your link? I had a problem like yours, with another script, due to turbolinks.

Comment: page wrapper ? Sorry I haven't understand it , are u talking about adding this on javascript?

Comment: Nop sorry, I misspoke. On the div that encompass your script and content, you can add `data-turbolinks="false"`. It fixed the problem for me (I had to add this data-attribute on the guest homepage’s body)

Comment: I have added like below
<div class="mui-textfield" data-turbolinks="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value='' id="user_id">
            <%= text_field_tag :location, nil, id: 'txtPlaces', class: "form-text", placeholder: '', required: true %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :full_address, nil, id: 'full_address', class: "form-text", placeholder: '' %>
          </div>  but not works

Comment: Your script still outside this div with the data-turbolinks attribute so that could explain why you have to reload. Maybe you should add the script in your assets and load it in the head with the asset pipeline